Pandas Map Dictionary with Multiple Values to Dataframe
I have the following dataframe:
data = [['BALANCED', 'Corp EUR'], ['YIELD', 'Corp USD'], ['GROWTH', 'HG CHF']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['STRATEGY', 'ASSET_CLASS']
df

    STRATEGY    ASSET_CLASS
0   BALANCED    Corp EUR
1   YIELD       Corp USD
2   GROWTH      HG CHF

My objective is to assign a specific value from a dictionary with multiple values depending on the value in column "STRATEGY". The dictionary containing the different asset classes looks as follows:
my_dict = {'HG CHF': [5, 2, 3, 4],
           'Corp EUR': [4, 6, 8, 7],
           'Corp USD': [9, 7.5, 5.3, 6],
          }
my_dict

{'HG CHF': [5, 2, 3, 4],
 'Corp EUR': [4, 6, 8, 7],
 'Corp USD': [9, 7.5, 5.3, 6]}

In the dictionary, each value depicts a specific strategy. In this case, YIELD include all second values, BALANCED all third values and GROWTH all fourth values, respectively. Essentially, what I'd like to obtain is the following output:
   STRATEGY ASSET_CLASS  TARGET
0  BALANCED    Corp EUR     8.0
1     YIELD    Corp USD     7.5
2    GROWTH      HG CHF     4.0

How can I correctly tell Python which value in the dictionary to access? Below command maps all values:
df['TARGET'] = df['ASSET_CLASS'].map(my_dict)

   STRATEGY ASSET_CLASS            TARGET
0  BALANCED    Corp EUR      [4, 6, 8, 7]
1     YIELD    Corp USD  [9, 7.5, 5.3, 6]
2    GROWTH      HG CHF      [5, 2, 3, 4]

Any suggestion is much appreciated!! Thanks a lot in advance!!

Use a second dictionary and a list comprehension with zip:
# which item should be picked?
nth = {'YIELD': 1, 'BALANCED': 2, 'GROWTH': 3}

df['TARGET'] = [
    my_dict[a][nth[s]] for s, a in zip(df['STRATEGY'], df['ASSET_CLASS'])
]

Output:
   STRATEGY ASSET_CLASS  TARGET
0  BALANCED    Corp EUR     8.0
1     YIELD    Corp USD     7.5
2    GROWTH      HG CHF     4.0

If there is a chance that the lists don't have enough items, you can add a safety check:
# let's pick the 5th item for "GROWTH"
nth = {'YIELD': 1, 'BALANCED': 2, 'GROWTH': 5}

df['TARGET'] = [
    d[n] if (n := nth[s]) < len(d := my_dict[a]) else None
    for s, a in zip(df['STRATEGY'], df['ASSET_CLASS'])
]

Example:
   STRATEGY ASSET_CLASS  TARGET
0  BALANCED    Corp EUR     8.0
1     YIELD    Corp USD     7.5
2    GROWTH      HG CHF     NaN


One more question: the dataframe I'm using contains values for which no matching keys exist in the dictionary, thus yielding the "KeyError" message. Is there a way to skip those records and just put "None" as value for the column "TARGET_DUR"?

Yes, replace my_dict[a] by my_dict.get(a, []) in the second approach.

Or use d[n] if a in my_dict and (n := nth[s]) < len(d := my_dict[a]) else None

I would implement function based on

YIELD include all second values, BALANCED all third values and GROWTH
all fourth values,

to be used with pandas.DataFrame.apply as follows
import pandas as pd


def get_target_value(row):
    if row.STRATEGY == "YIELD":
        return row.TARGET[1]
    if row.STRATEGY == "BALANCED":
        return row.TARGET[2]
    if row.STRATEGY == "GROWTH":
        return row.TARGET[3]


data = [['BALANCED', 'Corp EUR'], ['YIELD', 'Corp USD'], ['GROWTH', 'HG CHF']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['STRATEGY', 'ASSET_CLASS'])
my_dict = {'HG CHF': [5, 2, 3, 4],
           'Corp EUR': [4, 6, 8, 7],
           'Corp USD': [9, 7.5, 5.3, 6],
          }
df['TARGET'] = df['ASSET_CLASS'].map(my_dict)
df['TARGET'] = df.apply(get_target_value,axis=1)
print(df)

gives output
   STRATEGY ASSET_CLASS  TARGET
0  BALANCED    Corp EUR     8.0
1     YIELD    Corp USD     7.5
2    GROWTH      HG CHF     4.0

Observe there values are less one w.r.t. your description as in python lists indexing starts with 0.

Mapping then applying after is likely to be slow because you're building the TARGET column twice (thought it probably doesn't matter much on a sample this small...). If you're going to use apply rowise you might as well just make your get_target_value use the values from STRATEGY and ASSET_CLASS to pull the values directly from the dictionary and drop the map step.
